# What counts as inactive time for the purposes of sleep/hibernation?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

My computer was in the middle of running a long computation in Matlab when it went into hibernation mode. Clearly I am not understanding the definition of "how long your computer is inactive", see screenshot:

[image: screenshot of advanced power options settings]

Can someone please explain what the times in the drop down boxes for the sleep/hibernate settings mean in terms of activity.

Comment: Assuming Windows consider "Inactive State" to be the same as "[Idle State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx)", either MatLab is set to Low Priority, or it has finished its operation. But of course, it is possible Windows does not consider "Inactive State" to be the same as "Idle State".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting it simply - the only two activities that reliably prevent sleep/hibernate are *keyboard* and *mouse/touch* input.

In all other cases, applications must explicitly and (in my experience) periodically tell Windows ["I still need you!"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373233(v=vs.85).aspx) if they require the computer to stay awake. Media player applications are a good example.

If Matlab has no option to "keep your PC awake", you'll have to disable sleep/hibernate while you perform long-running calculations.

Comment: How about something like downloading?